# Cannot calculate Business Days between two dates? Converting dtype('<M8[ns]') to dtype('<M8[D]')?

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe, datetime

I wish to calculate Working days (Excluding Sunday and Saturday) between two dates, one is within a dataframe column and the other is todays current date, but an error appears:

```
REF8_df['Days_Dif'] = np.busday_count(REF8_df['Session1_Date'], Todays_Date)
File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in busday_count
TypeError: Iterator operand 0 dtype could not be cast from dtype('<M8[ns]') to dtype('<M8[D]') according to the rule 'safe'
```

My Code:

```
df = Main_Database['Session1_Date']
Todays_Date = np.datetime64('today', dtype='datetime64[D]')
df['Session1_Date'] = df['Session1_Date'].values.astype('datetime64[D]')
df['Days_Difference'] = np.busday_count(df['Session1_Date'], Todays_Date)
```

I'm confused as to why this does not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem probably arises because data frames and series only hold datetime-like objects as objects of dtype datetime64[ns]. Therefore this line:

```
df['Session1_Date'] = df['Session1_Date'].values.astype('datetime64[D]')
```

does not store the conversion to .datetime64[D] you are aiming to achieve. The solution below works.

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create a toy data frame
dates = pd.date_range(datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 5, 0, 
                      0), datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 20, 7, 0),freq='D')

var_1 = np.random.sample(dates.size)
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Var_1': var_1, 'Session1_Date': dates})
df = df[['Session1_Date', 'Var_1']]
df.head()

# Calculate today's date and convert to 'M8[D]'
Todays_Date = np.datetime64('today')

# Calculate the business days
df['Days_Difference'] = np.busday_count(df['Session1_Date'].values.astype('M8[D]'), Todays_Date)

df.head()
```

Output

```
df.head() # Original data frame
Out[89]: 
  Session1_Date     Var_1
0    2019-04-05  0.625200
1    2019-04-06  0.482555
2    2019-04-07  0.701814
3    2019-04-08  0.876485
4    2019-04-09  0.117023

df.head() # With computed business days
Out[90]: 
  Session1_Date     Var_1  Days_Difference
0    2019-04-05  0.625200              166
1    2019-04-06  0.482555              165
2    2019-04-07  0.701814              165
3    2019-04-08  0.876485              165
4    2019-04-09  0.117023              164
```